# Using gcc as linker for assembly code not working

Tags: macos, assembly, gcc, linker, nasm

I am trying to make a simple compiler just for fun, and i have been struggling to use gcc as my linker for my assembly code. i want to use the puts function from the c standard library but it doesn't work, even when not using the c standard library at all. i am working on a apple silicon computer with Monterey operating system

i tried to run a very basic hello world program:

```
section .data
message: db "Hello, world!", 10
section .text
global _main

_main:
    mov rax, 0x2000004
    mov rdx, 14
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    syscall
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

and when i run `nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm`
and `ld -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem -o hello hello.o`
and run it, it just works perfectly fine.
but when i try to use gcc for the linking proces (when using this command: `gcc hello.o`)
it gives the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file hello.o, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

what is happening here? do i need to use a different command?
Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: You have an x86 gcc toolchain for some reason.  Get one for the right architecture.

Comment: Fuz meant to say you have an **ARM** GCC, you need x86-64 GCC.  (You might have both, if you run under `arch`.)

Comment: thanks a lot for answering! does anyone now how i should install the x86_64 version of gcc on a macbook m1?